# Using local file system instead of remote MinIO storage

Tags: java, spring-boot, filesystems, minio

There is a **Spring Boot** based application that uses an external **MinIO** storage.
According to the latest requirement the app should also run on a PC that won't have a connection to a MinIO storage. It should use **local file system** instead. Running a MinIO docker container on the PC isn't allowed.

Currently the app has the following configuration for the MinIO client

```
@Configuration
public class MinioClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MinioClient minioClient(@Value("${company.config.minio.host}") String host,
                                   @Value("${company.config.minio.access-key}") String accessKey,
                                   @Value("${company.config.minio.secret-key}") String secretKey,
                                   @Value("${company.config.minio.region}") String region,
                                   @Value("${company.config.minio.connection-timeout:10s}") Duration connectTimeout,
                                   @Value("${company.config.minio.read-timeout:30s}") Duration readTimeout,
                                   @Value("${company.config.minio.write-timeout:30s}") Duration writeTimeout
    ) {
        final var okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(connectTimeout)
            .readTimeout(readTimeout)
            .writeTimeout(writeTimeout)
            .build();

        return MinioClient.builder()
                          .endpoint(host)
                          .region(region)
                          .httpClient(okHttpClient)
                          .credentials(accessKey, secretKey)
                          .build();
    }

}
```

and uses it for bucket creation, file upload, etc.

```
minioClient.makeBucket(...)
minioClient.uploadObject(...)
minioClient.listBuckets(...)
...
```

My first thought was to extend the MinioClient and override its methods, that would work with local file system. Something like that:

```
class LocalStorageMinioClient extends MinioClient {

        protected LocalStorageMinioClient(MinioClient client) {
                super(client);
        }
}
```

And the app would have an option that would allow users to switch the implementation.
But I'm concerned about the amount of work related to overriding/implementation.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Is there any reason why the app couldn't just run MinIO locally on the same PC when it starts up?

Comment: @root In such a case it will be considered as an undesired resource consumption.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way would be to implement an abstraction over the MinioClient, something like `StorageService`

```
public interface StorageService {
   void makeBucket();
   void listBuckets();
   ....
}
```

and have an implementation for Minio

```
public class MinioStorageService {
   public MinioStorageService(MinioClient client) { ... }
   public void makeBucket() { client.xxx(); }
   public void listBuckets() { client.xxx(); }
   ....
}
```

and an implementation for local file system

```
public class LocalFilesystemStorageService {
   public LocalFilesystemStorageService() { ... }
   public void makeBucket() { ... use file system ... }
   public void listBuckets() { ... use file system ... }
   ....
}
```

In your code you should now be using `StorageService` everywhere

```
public class MyAppService {
  public MyAppService(StorageService storage) { ... }

  public void doSomething() { 
     storage.listBuckets(); 
     ...
     storage.makeBucket();
  }
}
```

And have a configuration class that will create the right bean based on something (for example setting `myapp.storage=minio` or `myapp.storage=filesystem` when running the application)

```
@Configuration
public class StorageConfiguration {
  
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myapp", name = "storage", havingValue = "minio")
  public StorageService minioStorageService(MinioClient client) {
    return new MinioStorageService(client);
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myapp", name = "storage", havingValue = "filesystem")
  public StorageService filesystemStorageService() {
    return new FilesystemStorageService();
  }
}
```

Now when you run the app `java -jar myapp.jar --myapp.storage=filesystem` you are in local file system mode and if you run with `java -jar myapp.jar --myapp.storage=minio` you're working with Minio.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. 
I am finding something like [flysystem (PHP)](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) or [filestash (Golang)](https://github.com/mickael-kerjean/filestash) in Java/Spring ecosystem but I haven't found yet. My idea is use filestash like a third party service of my current system, build a authorization mechanism in Spring boot then call API to filestash service, hope it will work